# Best use of torque bow

Tags: gears-of-war

I am new to Gears of War multiplayer. I am really interested in the Torque Bow, but I cannot play effectively due to its long aim time.
Is there a solution to use it in quick successions in close quarters?

Comment: Which game are you talking about?

Comment: Gears of war 1 mainly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Not really.*

In all of the Gears of War series, the Torque Bow works the same.  It's not meant to be used in close quarters at all apart from a few "lucky shots" you might be able to pull off.  If anything, the Torque Bow can be compared to that of the Longshot.  If you manage to charge the bow up enough and pull off a headshot, it's an instant kill, just like the Longshot.  But, aiming for a headshot with the Torque Bow is much harder than the Longshot in my opinion, which makes the Torque Bow more favorable in that all you have to do is stick the bolt into your opponent and let them explode.

You can however, use the Torque Bows explosion to try and kill people without actually shooting them directly.  If they are standing close enough to a bolt that's stuck in a wall or on the ground, they may die from it's explosion.  All that in mind, this weapon is not really meant for close quarters combat.  Failing to charge the bow up enough results in the bolt barely traveling any distance.  This, and it's slow rate of fire make it very poor for close range.